# How to display (print) vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf, disp

I have a vector `x = (1, 2, 3)` and I want to display (print) it as `Answer: (1, 2, 3)`.

I have tried many approaches, including:

```
disp('Answer: ')
strtrim(sprintf('%f ', x))
```

But I still can't get it to print in format which I need.

Could someone point me to the solution, please?

**EDIT:**
Both the values and (length of) `x` are not known in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I prefer the following, which is cleaner:

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
g=sprintf('%d ', x);
fprintf('Answer: %s\n', g)
```

which outputs

```
Answer: 1 2 3
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that for a matrix, all the rows will get lined up.

Comment: Right, sprintf can only be used with an array argument, so matrices get flattened. You should apply this to each row and concatenate the result.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
disp(sprintf('Answer: (%d, %d, %d)', x))
```

This results in

```
Answer: (1, 2, 3)
```

For vectors of arbitrary size, you can use

```
disp(strrep(['Answer: (' sprintf(' %d,', x) ')'], ',)', ')'))
```

An alternative way would be

```
disp(strrep(['Answer: (' num2str(x, ' %d,') ')'], ',)', ')'))
```

Comment: `fprintf('%s%s\b\b%s\n', 'Answer: (', sprintf('%d, ',x), ')');`
seems more clear, and does not output space after `(`.

Comment: @RomanShapovalov: I tried to avoid the backspace `\b` because if you capture the output to a file, it's going to contain literal backspaces.

Comment: Makes sense. You can modify your code to print `'%d, '` (note the position of the space) and then replace `', )'` with `')'` to avoid an excessive space.

Comment: seeing `,') ')'], ',)', ')'))` in a code makes me shudder, the effort to tell which of those are in strings and which are part of the code is ... *shudders*

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach that takes advantage of Matlab's `strjoin` function.  With `strjoin` it's easy to customize the delimiter between values.

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
fprintf('Answer: (%s)\n', strjoin(cellstr(num2str(x(:))),', '));
```

This results in: `Answer: (1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

You might try this way:

```
fprintf('%s: (%i,%i,%i)\r\n','Answer',1,2,3)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know the answer before running the program. Thought, it is obvious. Also, I don't even know the length of the resulting vector. So I need some general solution.

Comment: sorry, I just answered your post: I think you may somehow state you look for a general approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generalized solution that prints all elements of x the vector x in this format:

```
x=randperm(3);
s = repmat('%d,',1,length(x));
s(end)=[]; %Remove trailing comma

disp(sprintf(['Answer: (' s ')'], x))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line just read `disp(['Answer: (' s ')']);`?

Comment: @H.Muster That would not pass the values of x, it would print: `Answer: (%d,%d,%d)`. Note that the repmat just creates the syntax

Comment: You are right; I misread the second line of your code and therefore misjudged the last line.

Answer (score 0):

To print a vector which possibly has complex numbers-

```
fprintf('Answer: %s\n', sprintf('%d ', num2str(x)));
```